# sqlite read from javascript await

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I am trying to read sqlite database from javascript using sql.js example shown [here][1] using `fetch` command. However, when following example and adjusting it to my needs, I am stuck with error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and async generators
```

here is the code:

```
<head>
    <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js'></script>
    <script src='sql-wasm.js'></script>
    <meta charset="utf8" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id='myDiv'></div>
    <script>
        const sqlPromise = initSqlJs({
          locateFile: file => `https://sql.js.org/dist/${file}`
        });
        const dataPromise = fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/db.db").then(res => res.arrayBuffer());
        console.log(dataPromise)
        const [SQL, buf] = await Promise.all([sqlPromise, dataPromise])
        const db = new SQL.Database(new Uint8Array(buf));
        console.log(db)
    
    </script>
</body>
```

I understand the error, but `fetch` and `initSqlJs` are both `async` so this confuses me.
Any help is appreciated.
[1]: https://sql.js.org/#/?id=using-fetch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is basically saying you need to be in an async function to use `await` -- top-level `await` is not yet supported.

Wrap your code in an async function you then call:

```
<script>
async function main() {
  const sqlPromise = initSqlJs({
    locateFile: (file) => `https://sql.js.org/dist/${file}`,
  });
  const dataPromise = fetch(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/db.db",
  ).then((res) => res.arrayBuffer());
  console.log(dataPromise);
  const [SQL, buf] = await Promise.all([sqlPromise, dataPromise]);
  const db = new SQL.Database(new Uint8Array(buf));
  console.log(db);
}
main();
</script>
```